# Swift 2 - UIViewController with custom UITableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, custom-cell

I am by trade an Android and .NET developer and have released a few Android games.

I however have decided to try my hand in Swift 2 and have got most of my remake for a game done, however a little stuck on the best way to create a tableview, within a UIViewController and not a TableViewController.

The reason for this is I require a table to be embedded into the view to use up only half the screen. Im thinking I need to use Prototype cells, however really not sure how to add these all programmatically and everything I research points to doing this in a TableViewController.

Any basic code snippets or useful tutorials would be much appreciated.

Comment: once you have drag a tableview into your viewcontroller scene, you can connect the tableview to your class as a property(ctrl+drag, you should know it already). And after that, you can just set the tableview's datasource and delegate to your class. Then everything works just like a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is away to get it work and lets start from storyboard:

1-Drag `ViewController` and place your `TableView` and `TableViewCell` in it, and don't forget to give your cell an identifier .

2-Choose the `TableView` and from the connection inspector connect dataSource and delegate to your `ViewController`.

Now lets get into your class `ViewController` where you want to manage the `TableView`:

1- Implement the two tableview datasource and delegate protocols after class declaration `UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate`.

2- implement the required methods for dataSource, which is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection`,Also `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

I've created a sample with tableview and custom cell in `ViewController`:
https://yadi.sk/d/blxmBk0Fkdh33

Good luck!

Comment: I have implemented everything however how some reason my cellForRowAtIndexPath function is not getting called, not quite sure what im missing, I have all delegates, linked my cell to CustomCell.swift

Comment: @LandLPartners it's possible that you forgot to connect the datasource In storyboard as I mentioned in point number 2.

Comment: Ah perfect got it working, will have a play around and customise it to my needs now. Thanks